# $q.defer vs new promise(function (resolve, reject))

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have this html:

```
<div class="documentation-comment-view h100" ng-if="views.comment.selected">
    <div ng-include="views.comment.templateUrl" class="h100"></div>
</div>

<div class="documentation-annotation-view h100" ng-if="views.annotation.selected">
    <div ng-include="views.annotation.templateUrl" class="h100"></div>
</div>

<div class="documentation-localisation-view h100" ng-if="views.localization.selected">
    <div ng-include="views.localization.templateUrl" class="h100"></div>
</div>
```

The html content is changing depending of the value of a variable.

This is a part of the code in charge of it:

```
            myService.myFunction(param).then(function (retData) {

                //Do something here...

                changeView(scope.views.comment);
            });
```

And my problem is with promises and these two functions what are suppose to do the same:

Function1:

```
    function myFunction(param) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //Do something...
        deferred.resolve(retData);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Function 2:

```
    function myFunction(param) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            //Do something...

            resolve(retData);

        });
    }
```

Using any of both functions I don't get any errors and changeView is reached in both. But for any reason, the view is not changed using function 2. It works only using function 1.

Any help finding a reason why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: They are not the same, native promises do not trigger a digest cycle, whilst the q service does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Promise**

This is a pure Javascript function and it does not tell the angular about the completion of task. its a way to work with async calls when you are not using angular.
for more details on how it works [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

**$q**

An angular based service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing, and it tells the angular to digest once again over the elements and apply changes.
for more details [see this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)